# SPRING-BOOT MICROSERVICIOS::: Ejecutar application.yml de forma manual

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, clone, yml

necesito su ayuda por favor.
En el application.yml de un API llamada **configuration-server** clono un repositorio en el proyecto con algunas configuraciones que ocupo en otras APIS, estas configuraciones las actualizo de forma manual desde git, **lo que deseo es hacer un metodo o endpoint en otra API que pueda clonar este mismo repositorio *sin necesidad de reiniciar* el API de configuration-server**

---

> Application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://*******.org/****/******
          username: ******
          password: *******
          basedir: target/config
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos

Comment: Podes ampliar un poco lo que necesitas hacer? Que relación hay entre clonar el repositorio y reiniciar el configuration-server? Sugerencia: agrega, si existe, el tag de spring-cloud o spring-cloud-config.

Comment: Solo se clona el repo al iniciar o reiniciar el api. Si clona el repo sin problemas, solo que cuando agregamos un nuevo token de validacion a un archivo que esta en el repositorio otra api valida esos token pero si no esta, truena por seguridad y para que el repo baje el nuevo token se necesita reiniciar el api de configuration. Gracias